# Django - no access to "user" in Apache server, works on development server

Tags: django, apache, django-templates

The problem in all its simplicity is that the "user" object is accessible in the Django templates on the development server, but not on an Apache server. I have enabled 'django.core.context_processors.request' in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Here is an example piece of code from a template that behaves like it's supposed to on the development server, but not on the apache server (I put both user and request.user just to test it):

```
{{ user.get_profile.user_type }}
{{ request.user.get_profile.user_type }}
```

And here's a view:

```
class NotificationsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, CorrectUserMixin, TemplateView):

    error_message = 'Oops, something went wrong. \
                    The browser was trying to access someone else\'s notification list.'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        my_id           = self.request.user.id
        user_type       = self.request.user.get_profile().user_type

        if user_type == 'Developer':
            self.template_name  = 'my_notifications_developer.html'
            notifications       = RequestNotification.objects.filter(receiver__id = my_id, seen=False).order_by('-time_created')
        else:
            self.template_name  = 'my_notifications_charity.html'
            notifications       = RequestNotification.objects.filter(receiver__id = my_id, seen=False).order_by('-time_created')

        # needed for correct user mixin
        self.url_id            = self.kwargs['pk']
        return {
            'params':   kwargs,
            'notifications': notifications,
        }
```

Comment: Try running your site **temporarily** in debug mode with django-debug-toolbar to check which variables are available to the template.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll play around with it tonight, I hadn't even realised there is such a tool. Also, I can certainly test it on my local Apache server first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god, this was just a stupid error on my part as I'd created a profile in the admin interface and didn't manually attach a user profile to the user object...